# How to get sum of values for Male using Mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to `mongoDB` and having trouble getting the sum of values. I would like to get the sum of `Male` grouping by `Date`. 
How can I achieve this? I tried the below query, but did not work. I am having trouble retrieving the value of Male.

```
db.sales.aggregate(
[
  {
    $group : {
       _id: "$date",
       TotalMaleValue: { $sum: "$follower_demographics.gender.value" }
    }
  }
]
)
```

My documents look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("566dd67aef3ccf85743c4b10"),
        "date" : "somedate",
        "follower_demographics" : {
                "gender" : [
                        {
                                "key" : "Male",
                                "value" : 480
                        },
                        {
                                "key" : "Female",
                                "value" : 1705
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, `gender` is an `array`. So you need to modify your query a bit to `group by` an object inside an array.

- [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), the  `follower_demographics.gender` field. This would now give you a one document each for an object inside the `gender` array.
- [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), only those documents, that you are interested in, i.e those having the `gender` - `value` as `Male`.
- Now, [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by the `gender`-  `key` and get a [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of the `value` field.

Sample code:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
{$match:{"follower_demographics.gender.key":"Male"}},
{$unwind:"$follower_demographics.gender"},
{$match:{"follower_demographics.gender.key":"Male"}},
{$group:{"_id":"$date",
         "sum_of_males":{$sum:"$follower_demographics.gender.value"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

*If you are using MongoDB-3.2 or newer* then the best way to do this is to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) your documents and use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to return an array with only those sub-documents where "key" is "Male". The next stage in the pipeline will then be the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) stage where you denormalize your array. The final stage is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator to calculate sum of "value".

Of course the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage in the beginning of the the pipeline let you select only those documents that match your criteria. This can reduce the size of documents to process in the next stage of the pipeline.

```js
db.sales.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 
        'follower_demographics.gender': { '$elemMatch': {'key': 'Male' } }
    }}, 
    {
        '$project': {
            'date': 1, 
            'gender': { 
                '$filter': { 
                    'input': '$follower_demographics.gender', 
                    'as': 'g', 
                    'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$g.key', 'Male' ] } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': '$gender' },
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$date', 
        'TotalMaleValue': { '$sum': '$gender.value' }
    }}
])
```

Prior to MongoDB 3.2 you need to use the little known [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) operator after `$match`  to return an array with only those sub-documents where "key" is "Male".

```js
db.sales.aggregate([
    { '$match': { 
        'follower_demographics.gender': { '$elemMatch': { 'key': 'Male' }}
    }}, 
    { '$redact': {
        '$cond': [
            { '$or': [ { '$eq': [ '$key', 'Male' ] }, { '$not': '$key' } ] }, 
            '$$DESCEND', 
            '$$PRUNE'
        ] 
    }}, 
    { '$unwind': '$follower_demographics.gender' }, 
    { '$group': { 
        '_id': '$date', 
        'TotalMaleValue': { '$sum': '$follower_demographics.gender.value' }
    }}
 ])
```